# Connect to an existing Database in MySQL WorkBench

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, workbench, frm

I basically work with Sql Server for my databases. and now I was given a folder contains files with extensions **.frm**, **.ibd** and **.opt** and was asked to ensure the connection with these files (these files are the database as I understood) in order to process the data.

I looked for how to do this a lot but still didn't find a good answer.

I am using **Visual Studio 2013** and **C#**

Comment: How will connecting to a DB "release" the connection?  Your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry, release was a grammatical mistake. I modified my question. I just want to know how to read data of those files via my C# application

Comment: It sounds like the folder contains the DB files.  Have you tied copying it to the MySQL data folder?

Comment: I did, and I can see the tables in phpMyAdmin. but when I try to open any table it says the table doesn't exist